# What is the best way to do text formatting to a document in Python

Tags: python, document

I'm trying to format a semi-elaborate, logical, and very readable text document. I'm using the cmd module to parse text (search and match) in a file. The cmd module makes use of different functions (all that have the structure: def do_name(self, line):). I'm trying to understand how I can A) print a title and columns to a text document, and B) put my search findings in the appropriate locations in said document. I welcome your expertise .... Thanks!

Comment: Is this the built-in cmd module or a custom module? The built in one is for interactive command line programs, not for text parsing if I recall correctly.

Comment: @codeMonk - yes, it's the built-in cmd module

Comment: @user706808: Please include some code samples to explain what you're doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Reading the files**

[pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/) is a useful parsing library for structured text in python, I have successfully used it a great deal in the past.

*interesting but maybe not 100% applicable is*
[Hachoir](https://bitbucket.org/haypo/hachoir/wiki/Home) is an interesting file parsing library, it says it is for binary files, but text files **are** binary.

**Writing to your structured format**

[stringtemplate](http://www.stringtemplate.org/depot/ST3/python/release/PyStringTemplate-2.2/index.html) is a powerful library for inserting text into predefined locations in a text file.

Answer (score 2):

Would formatting with [Restructured Text](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/user/rst/quickref.html) and printing via [rst2pdf](http://code.google.com/p/rst2pdf/) help?